# Script to see running jobs in SQL Server with Job Start Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs, metadata, msdb

how to write script to see running jobs in SQL Server with Job Start Time?

```
SELECT sj.name, 
 sja.run_requested_date, 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), 
sja.stop_execution_date-sja.start_execution_date, 114) Duration
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
        ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
     WHERE sja.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY sja.run_requested_date desc;
```

Answer (score 62):

I posted a query a while back for getting a list of currently running jobs [here](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/09/05/a-t-sql-query-to-get-current-job-activity/).

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 
         AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id 
                         FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions 
                     ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

This has job name, job id, start time and what step it's running on.  If you follow the link above you can get some more detail on how I came up with it and what else is available.

Comment: Unfortunately, this script assumes that the currently running step is the one after the last completed step.  This isn't always the case.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into issues on one of my servers querying MSDB tables (aka code listed above) as one of my jobs would come up running, but it was not.  There is a system stored procedure that returns the execution status, but one cannot do a insert exec statement without an error.  Inside that is another system stored procedure that can be used with an insert exec statement.

```
INSERT INTO #Job
EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1,dbo
```

And the table to load it into:

```
CREATE TABLE #Job 
           (job_id               UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,  
           last_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,  
           last_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,  
           next_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,  
           next_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,  
           next_run_schedule_id  INT              NOT NULL,  
           requested_to_run      INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL  
           request_source        INT              NOT NULL,  
           request_source_id     sysname          COLLATE database_default NULL,  
           running               INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL  
           current_step          INT              NOT NULL,  
           current_retry_attempt INT              NOT NULL,  
           job_state             INT              NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the job name and run date and time, you can remove the date if you just want to see the name and time it runs.

```
SELECT
j.name AS 'JobName',
run_date,
run_time,
msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) AS 'RunDateTime'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON j.job_id = h.job_id 
WHERE j.enabled = 1  --Only Enabled Jobs
ORDER BY JobName, RunDateTime desc
```

Comment: Nice try but this lists jobs that ran - not the ones currently running at the time of running your script.

Answer (score 1):

This script will show the jobs currently running, as well as the step currently being executed:

```
-- From http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3491201_2/Detecting-The-State-of-a-SQL-Server-Agent-Job.htm
    CREATE TABLE #ENUM_JOB 
    ( 
        Job_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        Last_Run_Date INT, 
        Last_Run_Time INT, 
        Next_Run_Date INT, 
        Next_Run_Time INT, 
        Next_Run_Schedule_ID INT, 
        Requested_To_Run INT, 
        Request_Source INT, 
        Request_Source_ID VARCHAR(100), 
        Running INT, 
        Current_Step INT, 
        Current_Retry_Attempt INT, 
        State INT 
    )
    INSERT INTO #ENUM_JOB 
         EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1,garbage
    SELECT E.*, SJ.name AS job_name, SJS.step_name
        FROM #ENUM_JOB AS E
        JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS SJ
            ON SJ.job_id = E.Job_ID
        JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS SJS
            ON SJS.job_id = SJ.job_id
            AND SJS.step_id = E.Current_Step
    DROP TABLE #ENUM_JOB
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script returns:

- Job name
- Job id
- Job requested time
- Job execution time

```
SELECT sj.name
   , sja.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
   AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

Comment: For me this query returned disabled jobs that aren't actually running

Comment: The answer by @Kenneth is better as it returns currently running jobs only.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little around the houses possibly but does the trick

```
;WITH cJobDetail AS (
    SELECT 
        ja.job_id
        ,j.name
        ,ja.start_execution_date
        ,ja.last_executed_step_id
        --,j.start_step_id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN j.start_step_id = COALESCE(ja.last_executed_step_id,j.start_step_id) THEN j.start_step_id
            ELSE NULL
            END AS ExecutingStepId
        ,ja.job_history_id
        ,DATEDIFF(HOUR, ja.start_execution_date, COALESCE(ja.stop_execution_date,SYSDATETIME())) AS JobHourRunning
        ,DATEDIFF(SECOND, ja.start_execution_date, COALESCE(ja.stop_execution_date,SYSDATETIME())) / 60 % 60 AS JobMinuteRunning
        ,DATEDIFF(SECOND, ja.start_execution_date, COALESCE(ja.stop_execution_date,SYSDATETIME())) % 60 AS JobSecondRunning 
    FROM dbo.sysjobactivity ja
    INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobs j
        ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
    WHERE ja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
    AND ja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
)
,MaxJobHistoryStepStatus AS (
    SELECT jh.job_id, jh.step_id, MAX(jh.instance_id) AS MaxInstanceId
    FROM cJobDetail jd
    INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobhistory jh
        ON jd.job_id = jh.job_id
        AND jd.last_executed_step_id = jh.step_id
    GROUP BY jh.job_id, jh.step_id
    )

SELECT 
    jd.job_id
    ,jd.name
    ,jd.start_execution_date 
    ,COALESCE(
                CASE jh.run_status 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 
                                    CASE js.on_success_action
                                                            WHEN 3 THEN jd.last_executed_step_id + 1
                                                            WHEN 4 THEN js.on_success_step_id
                                    END
                        WHEN 0 THEN 
                                    CASE js.on_fail_action
                                                        WHEN 3 THEN jd.last_executed_step_id + 1
                                                        WHEN 4 THEN js.on_fail_step_id
                                    END
                END,jd.ExecutingStepId) AS StepId
    ,jd.JobHourRunning
    ,jd.JobMinuteRunning
    ,jd.JobSecondRunning                                
FROM cJobDetail jd
LEFT JOIN MaxJobHistoryStepStatus mhs
    ON jd.job_id = mhs.job_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysjobhistory jh
    ON mhs.MaxInstanceId = jh.instance_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON mhs.job_id = js.job_id
    AND mhs.step_id = js.step_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the current step number and name.  I had restarted the job in step 42; it was showing me step 1.

```
--  Show Currently running jobs and the current STEP NAME
--  Borrowing from noted URLs, I added code to get STEP NAME of CURRENTLY RUNNING STEP, FINALLY!!!

--  https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3491201_2/Detecting-The-State-of-a-SQL-Server-Agent-Job.htm
--  Let me show you a couple of different examples of how to call the "xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs" XP. This first example places job information for all jobs on the SQL Server instance into a temporary table named "#enum_job":
create table #enum_job ( 
    Job_ID uniqueidentifier, 
    Last_Run_Date int, 
    Last_Run_Time int, 
    Next_Run_Date int, 
    Next_Run_Time int, 
    Next_Run_Schedule_ID int, 
    Requested_To_Run int, 
    Request_Source int, 
    Request_Source_ID varchar(100), 
    Running int, 
    Current_Step int, 
    Current_Retry_Attempt int, 
    State int 
)       

-- LOAD TABLE WITH CURRENTLY RUNNING JOBS
insert into #enum_job 
     exec master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1,garbage  


--  CURRENTLY RUNNING SQL JOBS
--  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58859/script-to-see-running-jobs-in-sql-server-with-job-start-time
SELECT  ST.step_id,
    ST.step_name,
    AAA.*,
    GETDATE() ThisQueryRanAt,
    @@SERVERNAME as SERVERNAME__,
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
LEFT JOIN #enum_job AAA
  ON AAA.Job_ID  = ja.job_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps ST
    ON ST.job_id = ja.job_id
    AND ST.step_id = AAA.Current_Step
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;


drop table #enum_job
```