# Ola Hallengren Backup - stuck at 100% complete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, ola-hallengren

Full Backup started on 4/21 12 AM. While backing up one of the database, it is stuck.

[sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) shows following information

`wait_info: (1208ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJEC
CPU - 188,528,7853 and Increasing`

Also, I see another backup on the same database started 30mins later (Backup to VirtualDevice - I know this is AppAssure backup tool).

From SQLSkills [preemptive_os_waitforsingleobject](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/preemptive_os_waitforsingleobject/), I see `This wait type is when a thread is calling the Windows WaitForSingleObject function for synchronization with an external client process that is communicating using that object.`

And this is blocked for 2 days - I don't think one of the session will terminate itself until I kill the other.

However, LOG backups were happening without any issues. Only FULL backup and DIFF backup for that particular database was blocked.

I killed the AppAssure session and all the long queue went away from AppAssure.
I killed the DIFF backup as well. Now the only process left is this FULL backup with 100% complete with same `wait_info` and not willing to complete!!

I had no other options but to kill the FULL db backup and restart backup jobs.
And, the USER_DATABASES full refuses to start saying `the job is already running` but `sp_WhoIsActive` showed nothing. Also, there was nothing in `killed/rolled back` state.

[CurrentJobActivity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64091/107357) in msdb showed that the job was active. Had to right-click-stop under jobs and then start the job again!!

Any idea on how do we avoid this situation? (other than telling the IT-team to stop AppAssure?)

[EDIT]: Adding the version

`Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU8) (KB4013104) - 11.0.6594.0 (X64) 
    Mar 15 2017 10:52:31 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

**[EDIT2]: Another day - 4/26**

[image]

Memory Clerks at the time
[image]

Log shows this
[image]

Server Config: 
RAM: 24GB - 21.5GB for SQL Server
Processors: 8
Not much activity in this server - hardly 50 people access this SQL Server via Sharepoint.

Comment: You said it was blocked, which session or process was blocking it ?. I have a hunch this issue might not be directly related to SQL Server the wait type indicates that the call was transferred to windows and it was not able to finish its task and SQL Server is just waiting for it to finish its task.

Comment: One more thing are you dumping the backups on local drive or file share or Azure BLOB storage ?

Comment: Backups are saved to local drive

Comment: The `SQL Native backup` was not blocked by any session. `sp_WhoIsActive` reported the `percent_complete as 100`. The other backup (AppAssure) on the other hand was blocked by `SQL Native backup` (VSS thing)

Comment: What was the statement that was executing in DatabaseBackup? The BACKUP DATABASE command or something else?

Comment: It was the `BACKUP DATABASE` command. stuck at 100%. Also, the AppAssure tool had this statement `BACKUP DATABASE <same database being backed up at that moment> TO VIRTUAL DEVICE` - This was blocked by session that was running `BACKUP DATABASE TO DISK`

Comment: The issue is back. This time it is stuck backing up the same database (`which is <1MB, log file around 100MB`). There is no other process - as reported by sp_WhoIsActive. Note: The database being backed up is one of SharePoint database - `SIMPLE model` ; `wait_info: (1720ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJEC`

Comment: your server only has 3.6 GB of buffer pool??? I suspect your memory settings need looking at, and that the OS has enough left for it (think copying files...).

Comment: SQL has been allotted 21.5GB memory. Added the log file screenshot.