# Run status for in progress job in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem: I can't find a record with `run status = 4` in `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` while a job is in progress.

It appears just for some special job. If we have a running job, it does not show in SSMS (job->view history) and in msdb table and just when job finished, it records in msdb table with run status 1 or 0.

I want to know what the reason for this issue is, and why this happens just for some jobs, but not all jobs?

Comment: [sysjobhistory docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql) say _In most cases the data is updated only after the job step completes and the table typically contains no records for job steps that are currently in progress, but in some cases underlying processes do provide information about in progress job steps._ But it doesn't elaborate about which jobs do provide in-progress updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script to see running jobs in SQL Server with Job Start Time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58859/script-to-see-running-jobs-in-sql-server-with-job-start-time)

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty common question. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445825/how-to-know-status-of-currently-running-jobs) post over on Stack Overflow cover what you're looking for?